Successive quotients of the maximal ideal of the stalk of a variety
If we are given an irreducible variety $X$ of dimension $p$ and a regular point $x\in X$, call $A=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ its stalk and $\mathfrak{m}$ the maximal ideal and $k=A/\mathfrak{m}$ the residue field. My question is, what can be said about the dimension
$$d_n=\dim_k \mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}.$$
I know that if $X$ is a curve (ie $p=1$) $A$ is a discrete valuation ring, and $d_n=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ in that case. I also know that $d_1=p$, because that's the tangent space.
I had hoped that in the general case where $X$ is of dimension $p$, $A$ would be a valuation ring of rank $p$, and derive the value of $d_n$ that way, but it seems this is false in general ($A$ is in general not even a valuation ring). Hence I am quite stuck on understanding the structure of $A$, and understanding $d_n$ past $n=0$ or $1$
I have also found as an exercise in Fulton's Intersection Theory that states that $\sum_{n\leq t} d_n$ is, for $t\gg 1$ a polynomial of degree $p$ and leading coefficient $e/p!$ where $e$ is the multiplicity of the point, in this case $e=1$.
Thank you in advance for any help or references.

Note that $d_1 = \dim X$ holds if any only if $x$ is a regular point of $X$ (by definition of regularity).

Because it's a regular local ring, you have $ m^n / m^{n+1} = Sym^n (m/m^2) $ and $ m/m^2 $ is a $ p $-dimensional $ k $-vector space. With these facts you can compute $ d_n $

@CraniumClamp Is it obvious that this is the case ? I don't understand why it would be the case. Nonetheless this answers my question exactly, thank you.

See here for an explanation.

Do you know the answer to the corresponding question for smooth manifolds? There you're isolating the homogeneous terms of the Taylor series expansion of a smooth function. At a smooth point it's the same idea in algebraic geometry.

@QiaochuYuan That’s very insightful, I think I understand what is going on now.
